# How to print the accuracy of the prediction done by a saved model?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tf.keras

I trained a CNN to categorize between dogs and cats and saved it as: MiniProject_01.hdf5 with accuracy of 80%

Now I want to test my model. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import keras

CATEGORIES =["Dog", "Cat"]

def data(file):
    IMG_SIZE = 64
    img_array = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

model = keras.models.load_model("MiniProject_01.hdf5")

prediction = model.predict([data("dog13.jpg")])
print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[:])])
```

It just prints: Dog.

Can I get the percent accuracy/probability by which my model said it is a dog?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean is percentage confidence. You can use `prediction = model.predict_proba([data("dog13.jpg")])` to get it.

Answer (score 0):

`model.predict()` returns a 2dim array with the probability for each output.

So try it with `prediction[0][0]` for the Dog or `prediction[0][1]` for the Cat.